# differential geometry and symmetric spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

I'm studying    Helgason "Differential geometry and symmetric spaces "

but the textbook we are using is a little bit heavy going for me. Is there a best book to learn about these things?

Thank you.

Comment: I like O'neill's book for differential geometry.

Comment: There is a *ton* of stuff in that book. What in particular are you studying and looking for alternative sources for?

Comment: I suggest you read something else as an introduction to Riemannian geometry, say, do Carmo or Petersen. Both books do contain some basic results about symmetric spaces. Once you are comfortable with Riemannian geometry, then you can proceed with symmetric spaces. For a quick introduction see http://myweb.rz.uni-augsburg.de/~eschenbu/symspace.pdf.